# Java regex Android How to find any text in the String

Tags: java, android, regex

Hi I have some string.

```
String cos = "Something I do not know ThisIWantToFind Something I do not know";
```

And how I can find this with regex ?

I tried with:

```
result = cos.matches("(.*)ThisIWantToFind(.*)");
```

and

```
result = cos.matches("(.*?)ThisIWantToFind(.*?)");
```

but this not work :(

Comment: Have you tried: `result = cos.matches(".*ThisIWantToFind.*");`?

Comment: If `ThisIWantToFind` isn't a regular expression, can't you use `String#contains()` instead?

Comment: @AntonH Yes!  So this question is actually about a _typo_.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Just check if the String contains your word? @devbigOS

Comment: `(.*?)` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without regex

case sensitive

```
String cos = "Something I do not know ThisIWantToFind Something I do not know";
if (cos.indexOf("ThisIWantToFind") > -1)
{
   // found 
}
```

not case sensitive

```
String cos = "Something I do not know ThisIWantToFind Something I do not know";
if (cos.toUpperCase().indexOf("ThisIWantToFind".toUpperCase()) > -1)
{
   // found 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the regex is in the string or the position of the regex in the string?

for the first one, I guess this should work ..

```
boolean result = cos.matches(".*ThisIWantToFind.*");
```

?